# Bootstrap-table-export: icon not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap-table-export to be able to export data from a table, but the icon is weird:

[image: Weird icon on image]

Does anyone knows how to change this icon? I read the [docs](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/export#options), but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is a [glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). If you got this symbol instead of the normal [glyphicon-export](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_export&stacked=h), you should check if you are including the bootstrap correctly. The recommended CDN for Bootstrap is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Hope it helps.